# Persisting a JSON Object using Hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to store a JSON object in MySQL database in spring boot. I know I am doing something wrong but I a can't figure out what it is because I am fairly new to Spring.

I have a rest endpoint where I get the following JSON object (via HTTP PUT) and I need to store it in database so that the user can fetch it later (via HTTP GET).

```
{
  "A": {
    "Name": "Cat",
    "Age": "1"
  },
  "B": {
    "Name": "Dog",
    "Age": "2"
  },
  "C": {
    "Name": "Horse",
    "Age": "1"
  }
}
```

Note that in the above case The **number** **of** **keys** in the object may vary, Due to that requirement I am using a `HashMap` to catch the object in the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPostCollection(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Animal> hp) {

        hp.forEach((x, y) -> {
            postRepository.save(hp.get(x));
        });

        return "OK";

    }
```

As you can see in the method, I can iterate the `HashMap` and persist each `Animal` object in db. But I am looking for a way to persist the entire `HashMap` in a single record. I have did some reading and they suggest me to use a `@ManyToMany` mapping.

Can anyone point me in a direction to persist the `HashMap` in a different way? (or is using the `@ManyToMany` the only and right way to do this?)

Comment: "entire HashMap in a single record" ?? Or entire hashmap in a single db transaction?

Comment: I meant single record.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Maven dependency

The first thing you need to do is to set up the following [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/) Maven dependency in your project `pom.xml` configuration file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

### Domain model

Let's assume you have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(
    typeClass = JsonType.class, 
    defaultForType = JsonNode.class
)
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private JsonNode properties;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice the `@TypeDef` is used to instruct Hibernate to map the `JsonNode` object using the [`JsonType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/) offered by the Hibernate Types project.

### Testing time

Now, if you save an entity:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setIsbn( "978-9730228236" );
book.setProperties(
    JacksonUtil.toJsonNode(
        "{" +
        "   \"title\": \"High-Performance Java Persistence\"," +
        "   \"author\": \"Vlad Mihalcea\"," +
        "   \"publisher\": \"Amazon\"," +
        "   \"price\": 44.99" +
        "}"
    )
);
 
entityManager.persist( book );
```

Hibernate is going to generate the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO
    book 
(
    isbn, 
    properties, 
    id
) 
VALUES
(
    '978-9730228236', 
    '{"title":"High-Performance Java Persistence","author":"Vlad Mihalcea","publisher":"Amazon","price":44.99}',  
    1
)
```

And you can also load it back and modify it:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
 
Book book = session
    .bySimpleNaturalId( Book.class )
    .load( "978-9730228236" );
 
LOGGER.info( "Book details: {}", book.getProperties() );
 
book.setProperties(
    JacksonUtil.toJsonNode(
        "{" +
        "   \"title\": \"High-Performance Java Persistence\"," +
        "   \"author\": \"Vlad Mihalcea\"," +
        "   \"publisher\": \"Amazon\"," +
        "   \"price\": 44.99," +
        "   \"url\": \"https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/\"" +
        "}"
    )
);
```

Hibernate taking caare of the `UPDATE` statement for you:

```
SELECT  b.id AS id1_0_
FROM    book b
WHERE   b.isbn = '978-9730228236'
 
SELECT  b.id AS id1_0_0_ ,
        b.isbn AS isbn2_0_0_ ,
        b.properties AS properti3_0_0_
FROM    book b
WHERE   b.id = 1
 
-- Book details: {"price":44.99,"title":"High-Performance Java Persistence","author":"Vlad Mihalcea","publisher":"Amazon"}
 
UPDATE
    book 
SET
    properties = '{"title":"High-Performance Java Persistence","author":"Vlad Mihalcea","publisher":"Amazon","price":44.99,"url":"https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/"}'
WHERE
    id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! However, can you make this work with H2 database which does not know any JSON type? I use Spring Boot and H2 for testing. Perhaps overriding H2 dialect somehow to treat JSON type as text? But did not figure how.. Thanks

Comment: @VladMihalcea My integration tests do indeed use a MySQL database, but using MySQL for my JPA unit tests would be painful and absurd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FasterXML (or similar) to parse the Json into an actual object (you need to define the class) and use `Json.toJson(yourObj).toString()` to retrieve the Json String. It also simplifies working with the objects since your data class may also have functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is well structered, so usually theres no need to persist the entire map in one single record. You won't be able to use the Hibernate/JPA query functions and a lot more.

If you really want to persist the entire map in one single record, you could persist the map in its string representation and, as already proposed, use a JSON parser like Jackson to rebuild your HashMap

```
@Entity
public class Animals {

  private String animalsString;

  public void setAnimalsString(String val) {
    this.animalsString = val;
  }

  public String getAnimalsString() {
    return this.animalsMap;
  }

  public HashMap<String, Animal> getAnimalsMap() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<HashMap<String,Animal>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Animal>>() {};
    return mapper.readValue(animalsString, typeRef); 
  }

}
```

Your animal class:

```
public class Animal {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  /* getter and setter */
  /* ... */
}
```

And you could change your controller method to

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPostCollection(@RequestBody String hp) {
  Animals animals = new Animals();
  animals.setAnimalsString(hp);
  animalsRepository.save(hp);
  return "OK";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best option for me. Saving the Objects as string and map it to a Map.

Answer (score 0):

One animal is one record. You are saving more records, not one record. You can commit more records in one transaction. 
See: [How to persist a lot of entities (JPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649345/how-to-persist-a-lot-of-entities-jpa)