# Hibernate - serialize whole object to field

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization

I have following class:

```
class A{
  int id;
  String field1;
  String field2;
}
```

and I need to serialize this object of class `A` to database table `serialized_A` having only these two fields: `id`,`serialized_A`.

The question is - what is the easiest way to serialize whole object to JSON and then to field `serialized_A` and be able to find it and de-serialize using `id`?

I can do this using SQL, but is there any way to do it using only annotations?

Comment: You can use Jackson.

Comment: Yes. That is a part of it. I need to see how to use Hibernate annotations on this class to map this class to db table having only `id` and `serialized_A` columns.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736311/1776132) and [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/) might be of some help.

Comment: This works for properties inside class `A`. Seems like there is no easy way to serialize whole class A as JSON? (except creating additional class of course)

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942878/1776132 It exactly has what you are looking for