# Improve the performance of Spring boot JpaRepostiory on Save

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

Am working on fetching the data from an third party API and then I want to insert those record in to Oracle database.This will occurs on hourly basis. Sometimes the API returns more than 50,000 records for an hour. So that time , it takes so much of time to insert the record(Absolutely record size too large). But I want to know is there any other way to increase the performance of the insert query.

Following is the code I used for inserting the records:

```
List<ClassName> retrievedList=util.getResultFromApi(); //The function getResultFromApi may returns more than 50,000 records.

userInfoRepository.save(retrievedList);
```

UserInfoRepository is my JpaRepository. Can anyone please help me with the suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you have to improve `JpaRepository` and not the `database` itself?

Comment: What about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649345/how-to-persist-a-lot-of-entities-jpa

Comment: why dont you just use raw sql ?

Comment: Yes ,I want to improve JpaRepository, is there any options like Chunk @Pijotrek

Comment: Nope, the query will be generated dynamically, also using raw sql is not allowed in our project

Comment: And JPARepository is NOT THE JPA API (the `jpa` tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it faster, by calling `flush()` and `clear()` after a certain number of inserts.

```
int i = 0;
for(ClassName className: classNames) {
    dao.save(className);
    if(++i % 20 == 0) {
        dao.flushAndClear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a relational database is not the best way to do it. If you are going more write hard to your database. May be Mongo could be a better choice.